# Как убрать генерацию лишнего второго атрибута в XML?

Tags: c#, xml

Генерирую XML для Excel и столкнулся с проблемой, что при указании пространства имён для атрибута излишне генерируется второй атрибут `xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"` . Можно ли избавиться от него во время генерации?

```
 XmlAttribute expandedColumnCountAttr = doc.CreateAttribute("ss", "ExpandedColumnCount", "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet");
 expandedColumnCountAttr.Value = "24";
 tableElement.Attributes.Append(expandedColumnCountAttr);
```

На выходе:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="24" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" />
```

Изначально хотел пойти по пути наименьшего сопротивления `doc.CreateAttribute("ss:ExpandedColumnCount")`, но теряется пространство имён `ss:`.

Хочется получить на выходе:

```
<Table ss:ExpandedColumnCount="24" />
```

Comment: `ss` - это префикс. Пространство имён для него должно быть где-то определено. Либо в этом узле, либо в одном из узлов-предков.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov можешь пожалуйста поподробнее написать.

Comment: Вот это: `xmlns:ss="..."` - обязательно должно присутствовать в xml. Если не хочется в `Table`, то оно должно быть выше уровнем.